# How to use modInverse to recover initial bigInteger of modPow

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm trying to use `modInverse` in java to obtain the original value of biginteger. Suppose we have a in input:

```
a = bigIntegerSample.modPow(exponent, RSA_MOD);
```

How do I get the value of bigIntegerSample? I know both exponent and RSA_MOD.

I tried with:

```
bigIntegerSample = a.modInverse(RSA_MOD);
```

but it's wrong. Any hint?

Comment: Despite framing this as a Java problem is just basic RSA mathematics. Transforming the notation, `bigIntegerSample` is just the message `m` being encrypted, `exponent` is the encrypt exponent `e`, `a` is the ciphertext `c`, and `RSA_MOD` is the RSA modulus `n`. I chose this notation because it's what's used in the [wikipedia article describing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) RSA, which contains the answer to your question.

Comment: exponent in my case is `d`, not `e`! Or am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's `d` or `e`, you just use the other one to recover `m`.

Answer (score 0):

`a.modInverse(RSA_MOD)` gives you the multiplicative inverse of `a`. It's just `(a.modInverse(RSA_MOD) * a) % RSA_MOD == 1`. That doesn't help you much.

You are basically expecting a solution to the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). Cryptography is based on the assumption that there is no simple solution. You have encrypted your ciphertext and you want to decrypt it without the secret key. If you don't know the secret key this will be difficult... But if you know the secret key you can just do

```
BigInteger b = a.modPow(secretKey, RSA_MOD);
```

and now hopefully `bigIntegerSample == b`. That is what @President James K. Polk is telling you.